# Want the javascript on window.onload = init; to anchor "#top"

Tags: php, javascript

I am facing a problem with the java-script code...

html:

```
<div id="thumbs">
  <a href="link1.htm"><img src="images/Button_Watch.png"></a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// This function runs when the page loads and adds click events to the links

function init() {
  var links = document.getElementById('thumbs').getElementsByTagName('a');
  // ...
}

// Call our init function when the page loads

window.onload = init;
```

The code will take the link "link1.htm" on clicking a button image link under div id "thumb" to show dynamic content from outside the server without reloading the page. The content show in (`<div id="embed"></div>`). I want the same "Button_Watch.png" when click to scroll to the anchor `#top` to point to the part where the content changes dynamically(ie; in `<div id="embed">` position )

I think you got what I meant to convey, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick and simple solution.

**Javascript**:

```
function scrollToAnchor (anchor_name) {
  document.getElementsByName(anchor_name)[0].scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<a name="top"></a>

<!-- other content -->

<a href="link1.htm" onclick="scrollToAnchor('top');">
  <img src="images/Button_Watch.png">
</a>
```